# Periodic solutions to Riccati equations

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

Suppose $\alpha, L>0.$ Under what conditions (between $\alpha, L$) the Riccati equation

$d\Phi/dz=2i[\Phi(z)^2+\alpha Cos(2\pi z/L)\Phi(z)+1]$

can have a periodic solution with period  $L$ (under the initial assumption of $\Phi(0)=0$)?

Comment: Solve the equation, see what comes out...